# Derivation of Gauss law

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

For our surface, let our charge be situated at the center of a sphere, and recalling that its field is radial in direction
$$\oint_{Sphere}\vec E\cdot d\vec A=\oint_{Sphere} E\hat e_r\cdot d\vec A \\ ‎\\E\oint_{Sphere} dA =\bigg(\frac1{4\pi}\frac{q}{r^2}\bigg)(4\pi r^2)= q $$
Now by the divergence theorem
$$\oint_{Sphere}\vec E\cdot d\vec A=\iiint_{Sphere}\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E\,dV =q $$
Now since the sphere could be of any size, we will let the radius tend to zero, thus the volume of the sphere approaches that of our point charge. Hence writing $q=\iiint\rho\, dV$, we get
$$\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E=\rho $$

*This equation is exactly precise even though is derived from a special case of Gauss law, however since that case is what mattered for our point charges, it doesn't concern us. Thus this is a valid proof of the divergence of the electric field.*

Is the highlighted remark correct over here?

Comment: Did you write that remark, or someone else?

Comment: @J.G. This text is from my personal notes, so yes it was me who wrote that, but now I doubt its validity.

Comment: Here's a better version: _$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E}=\rho$ holds if there is only a single, point charge. But both sides of this equation are additive, so it holds for arbitrary charge distributions._

Comment: @J.G. can you please tell me the essential difference between the two?

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist I think the point is $E$ and $\rho$ formally refer to a point charge, but you may take $E' = \Sigma E_i$ and $\rho ' = \Sigma \rho _i$ for a collection of point charges, and $\nabla \cdot E' = \rho '$ still holds. Then just denote $E'$ as $E$ and $\rho '$ as $\rho$, so $\nabla \cdot E = \rho$ holds in general, with a slight abuse of notation.

Comment: Another attempt at formulating this statement: *By the superposition principle, if we can show that $\nabla \cdot E = \rho$ for a single point charge, then we can conclude that $\nabla \cdot E = \rho$ for any collection of point charges, where in the second equation $E$ refers to the total field and $\rho$ to the total charge density. The case of a single point charge is easy because we can exploit spherical symmetry.*